# Create a user on OrientDB using console

Tags: orientdb

I simply want to create a user in OrientDB 3.0.0m2 using the `console.sh`.

As said in the [documentation](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/console/Console-Modes.html#interactive-mode), I should be able to execute SQL statements.

Here is my use case.

In terminal 1, run the following:

```
docker run -it --name orientdb -p "2424:2424" -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass orientdb:3.0.0m2
```

In terminal 2, run the following:

```
docker run -it --rm --link orientdb:orientdb orientdb:3.0.0m2 /orientdb/bin/console.sh
OrientDB console v.3.0.0m2 (build 4abea780acc12595bad8cbdcc61ff96980725c3b) https://www.orientdb.com
Type 'help' to display all the supported commands.
orientdb> CREATE DATABASE remote:orientdb/db root rootpass PLOCAL

Creating database [remote:orientdb/db] using the storage type [PLOCAL]...SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Connecting to database [remote:orientdb/db] with user 'root'...OK
Database created successfully.

Current database is: remote:orientdb/db
orientdb {db=db}> CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY userpass ROLE admin

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error parsing query:

     ^
Encountered " <CREATE> "create "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <IF> ...
    <FOREACH> ...
    ";" ...
    <IF> ...

    DB name="db"
    Error Code="1"
    DB name="db"

orientdb {db=db}>
```

It seems that the `console.sh` doesn't understand the [SQL command `CREATE USER`](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Create-User.html). Is this a bug, or am I doing the things in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed a few hours ago, see https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7898

You can find the fix in latest snapshot https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-community/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/